# S3 Eventual Consistency: file parts are lost on PUT with overwrite

Tags: amazon-s3, append, aws-sdk, overwrite, eventual-consistency

I am using Amazon S3 to store a big amount of text files.
My software is in Java, and I am using the official S3 SDK.
Apart from create/delete/retrieve/, i often need to **append** new content to files.

S3 does not support append, so I have implemented an append operation that basically:
- with an S3 GET, obtains the file metadata from S3
- with an S3 GET, downloads the whole file into a local copy
- performs the append to the the local copy
- with an S3 PUT, uploads the local file on S3 overwriting the old one.

Appends are never performed concurrently.
I have tested the software, and so far it seems to work well.

And here’s my issue: in scenarios where appends are very very frequent, when I perform append big parts of my files are lost.
Might this depend on S3 eventual consistency on overwrite PUTs?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it could.  Eventual consistency means that the next `GET` of an object may or may not return the results of the last `PUT` when an object has been overwritten.

Enable bucket versioning and you should easily be able to identify what happens in these events by capturing and logging the object's version-id each time you upload or download it.

If the version you last uploaded isn't the one you subsequently download, that's a sign of eventual consistency causing the issue.

On the other hand, if you actively manage your download by specifically requesting the latest version using its last known version ID (which you'd need to capture when you `PUT` the object, and store somewhere that offers strongly-consistent reads, like DynamoDB or RDS) then you can always request the latest version explicitly when you download it.

Explicit requests for a specific version of an object solve the problem because they have no consistency limitations -- a given, specified version of an object either exists or doesn't.  The consistency issue is related to implicitly fetching the "latest" version of an object.  If the specific index replica that happens to serve your request hasn't yet learned of the latest version, it will serve up a prior version.

This holds true whether versioning is enabled, or not, because an overwrite of an object is not truly an overwrite, even in an unversioned bucket.  It's a store + update index to new internal storage location + purge old storage location operation.  This isn't documented but atomic overwrites and the consistency model dictate that it must necessarily be the case.

Comment: Thank you Michael for your great answer. 
Unfortunately I see that AWS bucket versioning is quite expensive, so I don't know if I'll be able to use it.

I guess that my real problem is the combo "no append feature" + "eventual consistency". If I just could perform append content without need to re-read the whole file, it would be much easier.

Comment: Versioning can be used in such a way that it is almost no different in cost than unversioned buckets.  The only added cost is for storing all the old versions, but old versions don't *have* to be retained. You can create a lifecycle policy to purge old versions after 1 day, and if you want to be even more aggressive then you can save the prior version's version-id in the current version's metadata, and when you open the current version, send a delete request for the prior one.

Comment: Both features are as they are for a reason, though.  Objects are atomic.  Appending defeats atomicity.  Eventual consistency for overwrites allows a substantial performance improvement in the number of read requests per second that are possible.